# Issue creating iOS "Fat Library".

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, static-libraries, lipo

I have a bash script that builds my iOS static library for both ARM and i386 architectures. I am then using lipo to combine the binaries into a single "combined" library so that it can be linked to in the simulator as well as on a device. For some reason when I attempt to link against the resulting fat library I still get linker errors complaining that symbols are not found for i386 when debugging. I'm wondering if I am not building the simulator or iphoneos libraries correctly before using lipo. Can someone help me out?

Here is my bash script:

```
    if [ $1 == "clean" ]
then
    echo -e "Perform Clean\n"
    if [ -d build ]
    then
        rm -r build
        exit 
    fi      
else
    echo -e "Begin combined build process.\n"
    XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    XCODEBUILD=$XCODEBUILD_PATH/xcodebuild
    echo -e "xcode build executable path: $XCODEBUILD\nBuiding i386 static library.\n"
    $XCODEBUILD -project MyLibrary.xcodeproj -target "MyLibrary" -sdk "iphonesimulator" -configuration "Release" clean build
    echo -e "Buiding ARM static library.\n"
    $XCODEBUILD -project MyLibrary.xcodeproj -target "MyLibrary" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration "Release" clean build
    echo -e "Combine ARM and i386 libs.\nOutput: build/combined/libMyLibrary.a\n"
    [ -d build/Release-combined ] || mkdir build/Release-combined 
    lipo -create -output "build/Release-combined/libMyLibrary.a" "build/Release-iphoneos/libMyLibrary.a" "build/Release-iphonesimulator/libMyLibrary.a"
    echo -e "Done!\n"
fi
exit
```

When I add link against the resulting lib "build/Release-combined/libMyLibrary.a". I get linking issues. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: does `file` report that you have both arch's?

Comment: Yes. It says I actually have 3. libMyLibrary.a: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
libMyLibrary.a (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library
libMyLibrary.a (for architecture armv7s): current ar archive random library
libMyLibrary.a (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library

Comment: you are missing x86_64 i bet that is the one used in the simulator

Comment: @GradyPlayer I think it's the reverse - it's building the 64 bit simulator version not the 32 one. But in any case he needs two simulator builds.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I was under the impression that the simulator always used i386. This must have been a false assumption. If you have an example of building the x86_64 and/or the 32 bit binary.. I'd mark it as an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are 2 ways to make gcc/clang build a different arch.

you can pass the `-m32` or `-m64` flag...

but it is more explicit to use the `-arch x86_64 -arch i386` flags which in apple clang and apple gcc can be passed at the same time.